# Как удалить экземпляр класса Python в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Делаю задачку "адресная книга".
Создаю экземпляры класса Contact, добавляя их в список, и записываю список в файл, потом при запуске считываю.
Все почти работает, но при удалении не вызывается метод `__del__` (деструктор) из-за того, как я полагаю, что удаляется не сам объект, а лишь элемент списка. Как мне можно удалить объект?

```
import pickle
class Contact:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number       
    def info(self):
        print(f'{self.name}: {self.number}')
    def __del__(self):
        print(f'Контакт {self.name}: {self.number} удален!')
try:
    with open('contacts', 'rb') as f:
        list_contacts = pickle.load(f)
except EOFError:
    list_contacts = []
while (True):
    action = input("Возможные действия:\n добавить - 1\n удалить - 2\n все контакты - 3\n выход - q\n> ")
    if action == '1':
        list_contacts.append(Contact(input("Имя: "), input("Номер: ")))
    elif action == '2':
        for i, j in enumerate(list_contacts, start=1):
            print(i, end=') ')
            j.info()
        select_for_del = int(input("Введите номер удаляемого контакта: "))
        del list_contacts[select_for_del - 1]
    elif action == '3':
        print('=' * 20)
        for x in list_contacts:
            x.info()
        print('=' * 20)
    elif action == 'q':
        with open('contacts', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(list_contacts, f)
        break
```

Comment: Если вопрос в том, чтобы выводилось сообщение - выводите его сами после del. Если вопрос в технических деталях - пока объект привязан хоть к одной переменной (например к переменной j в цикле выше удаления), он не будет удален. Да и то сборщик мусора может быть реализован ленивым и удалять объекты не сразу.

Comment: так чтобы его самому не выводить, я и прописал "принт" в теле класса

Comment: Ну, не делайте так) Вообще, потенциальный пользователь будет очень удивлен, когда при выходе из программы получит кучу сообщений, что все его драгоценные контакты удалены (просто потому что при выходе вся память при выходе из программы освобождается) Я думаю, это не очень полезное поведение) Лучше уж вручную выводить сообщение)

Comment: @insolor, не высвобождается память, как вы предполагаете, я протестил прогу.

Comment: да, об этом я не подумал, что все объекты будут удалены при выходе :D

Answer (score 0):

Я немного улучшил ваш код:

```
import pickle
class Contact:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number       
    def info(self):
        print(f'{self.name}: {self.number}')
    def _del(self):
        print(f'Контакт {self.name}: {self.number} удален!')
try:
    with open('contacts', 'rb') as f:
        list_contacts = pickle.load(f)
except:
    list_contacts = {}
while (True):
    action = input("Возможные действия:\n добавить - 1\n удалить - 2\n все контакты - 3\n выход - q\n> ")
    if action == '1':
        name = input('Имя: ')
        number = int(input("Номер: "))
        list_contacts[number] = Contact(name, number)
    elif action == '2':
        for i in list_contacts.values():
            i.info()
        select_for_del = int(input("Введите номер удаляемого контакта: "))
        list_contacts[select_for_del]._del()
        del list_contacts[select_for_del]
    elif action == '3':
        print('=' * 20)
        for x in list_contacts:
            x.info()
        print('=' * 20)
    elif action == 'q':
        with open('contacts', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(list_contacts, f)
        break
```

Я поэкспериментировал с выполнением кода, и вот что обнаружилось: сообщение о том что удалено либо появлялось на несколько пунктов дальше, либо не появлялось вообще. Дело в том что как и сказал @insolor в комментарии к вопросу, сборщик мусора был либо ленивый, либо скорее всего объекты и реально привязывались к `j`.

Я преобразовал список в словарь, так удобнее хранить номера. И просто вызываю `.__del()`. Потому что `.__del__()` для другого сделан.

Comment: __del разве не считается приватной? ее нельзя вызвать вне класса

Comment: Да, имена полей/методов класса с двойным подчеркиванием не доступны снаружи класса без дополнительных манипуляций, кроме "магических методов": https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YqiP.png